# How i can import script in R to powerBI?

Tags: r, powerbi

Good morning 
I need to import script in R to powerBI but When I execute this code:
library(rvest)

```
> library(httr)
> sess <- html_session("http://www.atb.com.tn/", user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.39 Safari/537.36"))
> pg <- jump_to(sess, "http://www.atb.com.tn/devise")
> dat <- content(pg$response, as="parsed")
> mydata= html_table(html_nodes(dat, "table")[[2]], header=TRUE)
```

I get this error message:
Détails : « ADO.NET : Erreur du script R.
Le chargement a nÚcessitÚ le package : xml2
Erreur : '>' inattendu(e) in ">"

Comment: Are you executing this code from a script, but including the ">"? If so, remove them. And please try to set your environment to English, makes it easier for non-Frenchspeakers to help you.

Comment: Looks like you are missing the xml2 package. Check if this is installed, otherwise install it.

Comment: Yes, I cheked. it's installed.And  I remove this symbol ">" but nothing change, always the error appears. Help me please